# Incorrect bounding box centre detection during object recognition, OpenCV, Python

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, object-detection, coco

I have a problem with defining the centre of an object using OpenCV (I'm using version 4.5.5.64). I am using "coco.names" for object recognition, and I have a function "show_distance" in my code, which is designed to calculate the centre of the bounding box of the recognised object. But the centre is calculated completely wrong. If the object is on the left side of the screen, the centre of the box is almost correctly positioned, but as the object moves to the right, the centre also shifts. Below I provide the project code, the project file on GitHub, and screenshots.

## **Code:**

```
import cv2

thres = 0.45  # Threshold to detect object

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

CLASS_FILE = "coco.names"
CONFIG_PATH = 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
WEIGHTS_PATH = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'
TEST_OBJECT = 'person'

cap.set(3, 1280)
cap.set(4, 720)
cap.set(10, 70)

def show_distance(img, box, screen_center_x, screen_center_y):
    obj_center_x = (box[0] + box[2]) // 2
    obj_center_y = (box[1] + box[3]) // 2
    distance_x = obj_center_x - screen_center_x
    distance_y = obj_center_y - screen_center_y
    
    text = f"Dist X: {distance_x}, Dist Y: {distance_y}"
    cv2.putText(img, text, (box[0] + 10, box[1] - 10),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 1)
    
    cv2.circle(img, (obj_center_x, obj_center_y), 10, (0, 255, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(img, (screen_center_x, screen_center_y), 10, (0, 0, 255))

def add_one_object(img, box, current_obj, confidence):
    color = (0, 255, 0)
    cv2.rectangle(img, box, color, thickness=2)
    cv2.putText(
        img, current_obj.upper(), (box[0] + 10, box[1] + 30),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

def main():
    classNames = []

    with open(CLASS_FILE, 'rt') as f:
        classNames = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

    net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(WEIGHTS_PATH, CONFIG_PATH)
    net.setInputSize(320, 320)
    net.setInputScale(1.0 / 127.5)
    net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
    net.setInputSwapRB(True)

    entered_name=TEST_OBJECT

    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold=thres)

        if len(classIds) != 0:
            screen_center_x = img.shape[1] // 2
            screen_center_y = img.shape[0] // 2

            for classId, confidence, box in zip(classIds.flatten(), confs.flatten(), bbox):
                if classNames[classId - 1].lower() == entered_name:
                    add_one_object(img, box, classNames[classId - 1], confidence)
                    show_distance(img, box, screen_center_x, screen_center_y)
                    break

        cv2.imshow('Output', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problematic part on GitHub:

[https://github.com/OlegQm/coco_objects_recognition/tree/main/stackoverflow_test](https://stackoverflow.com)

Screenshots (generalised: the problem is that the green circle is almost never inside the green box, although it should be. The red circle is the centre of the window.

[The object on the left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVpJA.png)

[The object on the middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8nGt.jpg)

[The object on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T473X.png)

I've tried changing the OpenCV version and checking the maths. It would be interesting to know at least if this problem is caused by any technical issues or my mistake, but a solution would be ideal.

Comment: Can you verify that ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt uses input resolution of 320x320?

Comment: According to google, the model uses 320x320 input in NHWC ordering. I don't know what the hogh level detection module does internslly, but the default data ordering in opencv dnn is NCHW. Maybe you are able to check that.

Comment: in opencv 4.5 the ObjectDetection model internally uses a `cv::blobFromImage` which only creates NCHW blobs. Your model needs NHWC input, so the model currently is incompatible to the input. In opencv 4.8 the function `blobFromImageWithParams` is used which (in theory) can set the input ordering (but I dont know whether it is settable or read from the model config, or...). See https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.5.5/modules/dnn/src/model.cpp processFrame function.

Comment: @Micka Thanks for the reply, the solution turned out to be much easier (it's below).

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was that I misunderstood the coordinates of the boundary box.

You'll need to replace:

```
obj_center_x = (box[0] + box[2]) // 2
obj_center_y = (box[1] + box[3]) // 2
```

with:

```
obj_center_x = (box[0] + box[2] // 2)
obj_center_y = (box[1] + box[3] // 2)
```

Comment: in other words: you thought it was `xyxy` but it really was `xywh` with the `xy` being a corner, not a center